# Recompiling a Kernel module from source

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, kernel-parameters

Good night,

I am trying to recompile a kernel module from its source (in case you are wondering, it is the b43 driver module) on Debian 11. I've ran into a problem, which is that I want to specify some of the options expressed in the Kconfig file. I've been doing so with:

`sudo make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules`

However, I get no .config, no menu with the module menu. Furthermore, `make menuconfig` does not work giving the following output:

`make: *** No rule to make target 'menuconfig'.  Stop.`

I am compiling the code in a folder which is out of the tree. I guess that doing this out of the tree is the cause of the menuconfig is failing. I tried to use the `kconfig-frontend` package, but I get no entries shown, eventhough Kconfig file should be correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "…make -C…"  "I am trying to recompile a kernel module from its source" ??? No! You are not! "I am compiling the code in a folder which is out of the tree" Fair enough but… how *far* is that  far ? Do you get the linux kernel tree available  anywhere I mean ? Did you care that, at least all headers will be found ? What is pwd when make menuconfig ? what are the makefiles available in the pwd ?

Comment: Ultimately : What are you doing wrong ? I just cannot tell precisely. Just too many are possible. While possibly easily correctable. We just do not get enough informations. (It could well be only me since I must acknowledge I do not know the b43 driver)

Comment: @MC68020 Thanks for the answer. The code is in a /home/user folder, and I have access to the include files as I have the linux-header package. The thing is that I cannot get a .config with the parameters that are presented in the `Kconfig` file. I want to debug the module. I cannot do `make menuconfig` in the directory of the external module (fair enough, i dont have the target coded in the custom makefile). So the question now is, how do one configure the external module with this Kconfig file.

Comment: OMG! b43 ! Broadcom! Of course ! I should have guessed ! yet another thingy that can't work without a firmware blob ! So sorry as43z ! Debugging that sort of things goes far beyond me. I understand this won't help you but… anyway : upvoting your question & wishing you the best in your quest.